# Chained dependency order in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-composer

I'm attempting to utilize the "Project References" feature in Eclipse for an embedded firmware project.  I'm using Code Composer Studio 7.0 which is essentially just a wrapper for Eclipse 4.6 with CDT 9.0 and JRE 8.  However, from what I can tell the features I'm trying to use are specific to the CDT.  The embedded firmware is broken up into several parts with a few libraries, an RTOS platform, and the "core" firmware.

The intention is that the dependencies of a project are automatically built and updated in the proper order whenever a build on the core firmware project is triggered.  However, due to some libraries building upon others I'm seeing some weird behavior that i don't quite understand.  The dependency graph is shown below.

[image]

As you can see, there's a maximum of four levels of dependency.  The issue that I'm seeing is that, while I've ordered the references in the order "Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->References" as [Platform, PAL, HAL, Features] for the firmware project, the build order doesn't seem to follow that specification.  The ordering seems to be semi-random.  After a clean sometimes the PAL will build first, other times the Features will.  The entire build ultimately fails when this happens due to dependencies not being accessible.  Is there an additional step I'm missing to get dependencies to build in the correct order, or are nested dependencies not supported by Eclipse for some reason?

Comment: Do the intermediary projects have their references explicit? i.e. the entire set of dependencies cannot be represented from just one project.

Comment: Yes, each intermediate project also has its dependencies defined.  However, this link (http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_ref.htm) does seem to imply that the dependency build order should be guaranteed.